# Add new rows to data frame, where one column stays the same while other column changes values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

sorry, if my title sounds a bit confusing. What I'm basically trying to do is adding new rows in a data frame, where I duplicate the value of each unique value of one column, while another column's new values are changing.

This is what my data frame looks like:

| id | year |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022 |
| 02 | 2022 |
| 03 | 2022 |
| ... | ... |
| 99 | 2022 |

And I want it to look like this:

| id | year |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022 |
| 01 | 2023 |
| 01 | 2024 |
| 02 | 2022 |
| 02 | 2023 |
| 02 | 2024 |
| 03 | 2022 |
| ... | ... |
| 99 | 2024 |

I.e. I want for every id to add the years 2023 and 2024 in the year column. I tried doing this with an apply function, but it always didn't work out, could you guys help me out in solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make a list comprehension and concat all dataframe years wirh increments of your desire. For example:

```
pd.concat([df.assign(year=df.year+increment) for increment in range(0,3)]).sort_values(by='id').reset_index(drop=True)
```

This will increment your dataframe to three years as follows. You can play around with range for the desired number of extensions:

| id | year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 |
| 1 | 2023 |
| 1 | 2024 |
| 2 | 2022 |
| 2 | 2023 |
| 2 | 2024 |
| 3 | 2022 |
| 3 | 2023 |
| 3 | 2024 |

Comment: I think using `numpy` is faster: your approach: `2.32 ms ± 742 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)`, mine: `257 µs ± 67.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`

Answer (score 1):

```
years = [2022 + i for i in range(3)]
# or
years = [2022,2023, 2024]
pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.repeat((data:=df.id.to_numpy()), len(years)).reshape(-1,len(years)).flatten(),
    'year': np.repeat(np.array(years), data.shape[0]).reshape(len(years), data.shape[0]).T.flatten()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to make two copies of your current dataframe and change accordingly the year date to 2023 and 2024. After you do that, concatenate all 3 datasets together using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Comment: yes, that would work, but my original dataframe is alot bigger, i.e. there I need to add more than just two years, which would take up a lot of time